# How to iterate through your python script even if one statement failed?

Tags: python, ssh, automation, paramiko

I am trying to execute certain commands on list of cisco boxes using paramiko, if a command fails to execute on one box, it fails to progress in the code and exits out. I want the code the code to continue, even if it fails to login in one device or unable top execute anything

This reads a ts.txt file with list of devices to login and execute some commands,

```
with open("ts.txt") as f:
    x= [l.strip() for l in f]

    for line in x:

            ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            ssh_client.connect(hostname=line,username=username,password=password)

            print "Successful connection", line

            remote_connection = ssh_client.invoke_shell()


            remote_connection.send("sh ver")
            remote_connection.send("\n")
```

Error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko-2.4.0-py2.7.egg/paramiko/client.py", line 714, in _auth
```

If it fails to login in one device, it exits, I want it continue the rest of the list.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Read on catching exceptions

Answer (score 1):

From the python docs on try/except blocks:

> First, the try clause (the statement(s) between the try and except keywords) is executed.
>   If no exception occurs, the except clause is skipped and execution of the try statement is finished.
>   If an exception occurs during execution of the try clause, the rest of the clause is skipped. Then if its type matches the exception named after the except keyword, the except clause is executed, and then execution continues after the try statement.
>   If an exception occurs which does not match the exception named in the except clause, it is passed on to outer try statements; if no handler is found, it is an unhandled exception and execution stops with a message as shown above.

```py
for line in x:
    try:
        ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh_client.connect(hostname=line,username=username,password=password)

        print "Successful connection", line
        remote_connection = ssh_client.invoke_shell()
        remote_connection.send("sh ver")
        remote_connection.send("\n")
    except Exception as e:
        print "Error: " + e
```

Note that `except Exception as e` will catch ALL exceptions, not just the one you want.

Comment: @user12132912 If this case if finished I would appreciate if you clicked the little tick on the left, underneath the upvote / downvote. Just to mark this question as answered :D

Comment: how can I have 2 try statements, I want the script to try one username/pwd, if that fails, try another set of username2/pwd2, execute certain show commands and finally continue to next line if both of the passwords fail